# Sort a dictionary using index position of keys in a base list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a base list

```
li = ['fca', 'fc_add', 'fca_2', 'fcadd_2', 'Red_Exis', 'G_Exis', 'P_Exis', 'fam_1']
```

and want to use the index position of items in the list to sort the following dictionary

where list items are keys.

```
dic = {'G_Exis': 'abc', 'fca': '210Y', 'Red_Exis': 107, 'fc_add': '999 Des ST.'}
```

I need the final sorted dictionary to look like the following:

```
fin_dic = {'fca': '210Y', 'fc_add': '999 Des ST.', 'Red_Exis': 107, 'G_Exis': 'abc'}
```

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Dict's don't keep order, use `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict()

for item in li:
    if item in dic:
        od[item] = dic[item]
print od

OrderedDict([('fca', '210Y'), ('fc_add', '999 Des ST.'), ('Red_Exis', 107),
             ('G_Exis', 'abc')])
```

or as a oneliner:

```
OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda t: li.index(t[0])))
```